# htaccess redirect only works if file doesn't exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a file in my server to the same file in another server using htaccess and Redirect, my code is like:

```
Redirect /folder1/MyFile.zip http://www.otherserver/folder123/MyFile.zip
```

but it only seems to work if the file (or folder) in the original server doesn't exists, if I rename the folder it works fine, for sample.

I have to redirect the files one by one because they are on different paths in the new server (it's an online storage server) and don't want permanent redirects because in case of failure of the new server I only have to delete the htaccess file to get access again to the old files.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your htaccess file (you can edit it into your post above)?

Comment: The code is:
Redirect /folder1/MyFile.zip http://www.otherserver/folder123/MyFile.zip

it works if I rename the original file but not if it's still present

Comment: That's not the full contents of your htaccess file is it?

Comment: That's the content of the htaccess file I place in folder1 and it works renaming or deleting the original file

Comment: Add `RewriteEngine On` before the redirect and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

  RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Try this code.........